# Time to first byte 6secs Openshift

Tags: openshift

I am using this template (https://github.com/openshift-evangelists/php-quickstart) on a start node west 2 on Openshift. I assigned 256MB on the php container and 256MB on the MySQL container.

I have no data on MySQL and with really bare bone php scripts the time to first byte (TTFB) is 6 seconds. I don't get any delays to other websites like this and definitely not on my old Openshift 2 installation.

Is this normal? Is Openshift 3 slower like that for the free (starter) services? Or is there something I am doing wrong? Any way I can troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

256MB is too little for MySQL, it usually wants to use more than that from what I have seen and why the default was set to 512MB. Unless that is, that it is dynamically working out how much memory it has available and tries to gobble as much as possible.

The behaviour with slow responses is a known issue which has been affecting a number of the Online Starter environments on and off. The issue is still being investigated and a solution implemented.

You can verify actual response times by getting inside the container using `oc rsh` or the web console and using `curl` against `$HOSTNAME:8080`.